Who portrayed Sophia in "The Walking Dead: Daryl Dixon"?
The Walking Dead: Daryl Dixon features a recreation of a memorable scene from Season 2 (2011) of the original The Walking Dead series in the first episode of its second season, "La Gentillesse des Étrangers" (2024). This recreated scene shows Carol Peletier's daughter, Sophia, emerging from a barn as a zombie.



The original scene was a heartbreaking moment that marked the end of a major storyline. Rick's group had spent a significant amount of time searching for Sophia, with Carol clinging to hope that they'd find her daughter alive. When zombie Sophia finally appeared, Carol's grief was palpable, and viewers felt the weight of her loss.
I've been unable to find any information about the actor who played Sophia in Daryl Dixon. I've checked both the IMDb credits and the end-of-episode credits, but there seems to be no mention of who portrayed zombie Sophia.
Who portrayed zombie Sophia in The Walking Dead: Daryl Dixon?

This might be incorrect as i haven't watched TWD for a long time and have not watched the series mentioned.
Also, the website I got this from isn't a canonical source...
but it appears to be Sandra Brunelle:


https://x.com/TWDFans_AMC/status/1840687629182120039
https://walkingdead.fandom.com/wiki/Sophia_Peletier_(TV_Series)#cite_note-1
https://walkingdead.fandom.com/wiki/La_Gentillesse_Des_%C3%89trangers#Other_Cast

Uncredited
Sandra Brunelle as Sophia Peletier (Hallucination)

